# Echo include value - php

Tags: php

I want to print out the value of my include php file into some content.
I am adding this code into my template:

```
<li>Earn up to <?php include("btc.php"); echo $btc4cents  ?>  BTC per click</li>
```

My btc.php is showing me the right number:

```
<?php
 $btc4cents = file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=0.04");
 echo $btc4cents
?>
```

but it dosent show the value of it on my website?

Comment: I cant... the main script is done by another code, and only way to add it into the .tpl file is like this he told me.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the '&' between your request variables in the url.
https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=0.04

Comment: on my btc.php I hav the & ... I just forgot to past it here.

Comment: ok. what about ; after echo $btc4cents

Comment: i try to use `echo file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=0.04");` and all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would include the php file above, then echo the variable in the text..

```
<?php
include("btc.php");
echo "<li>Earn up to {$btc4cents} BTC per click</li>";
?>
```

btc.php:

```
<?php
 $btc4cents = file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=0.04");
?>
```

Comment: Ignore me! I've removed the comment. I didn't see that bit...